# MATLAB: Finding coordinates of value in multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, matlab, find, coordinates, multidimensional-array

I have a three-dimensional array, and I'd like to be able to find a specific value and get the three coordinates.

For example, if I have:

`A = [2 4 6; 8 10 12]`

`A(:,:,2) = [5 7 9; 11 13 15]`

and I want to find where `7` is, I'd like to get the coordinates `i = 1` `j = 2` `k = 2`

I've tried variations of `find(A == 7)`, but I haven't got anywhere yet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The function you seek is `ind2sub`:

```
[i,j,k]=ind2sub(size(A), find(A==7))
i =
     1
j =
     2
k =
     2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use find to locate nonzero elements in an array, but it requires a little bit of arithmetic. From the documentation:

> `[row,col] = find(X, ...)` returns the row and column indices of the
>   nonzero entries in the matrix X. This syntax is especially useful when
>   working with sparse matrices. If X is an N-dimensional array with N >
>   2, col contains linear indices for the columns. For example, for a
>   5-by-7-by-3 array X with a nonzero element at X(4,2,3), find returns 4
>   in row and 16 in col. That is, (7 columns in page 1) + (7 columns in
>   page 2) + (2 columns in page 3) = 16.

If the matrix `M` has dimensions `a x b x c`, then the indices `(i,j,k)` for some value `x` are:

```
[row,col] = find(A==x);
i = row;
j = mod(col,b);
k = ceil(col/b);
```